# Moving of the Shared JS runtime from preview to stable mode

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, excel-addins

Do you have any information if the **Shared JS runtime** is planned to move from preview to a **stable** version? Do you have any updates regarding this functionality? We plan to use it in our add-in and it will be great to understand the Runtime functionality future.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We can't give you a timeline, but we do plan to release this feature after a preview period.

Comment: Ok, thanks for a quick response!
As a rule, how long does the preview period last (i.e. approx. 3months, 6 months etc).?

Comment: There's no pattern. We have one API that's been in preview for almost 3 years. But others go from preview to release in a few weeks.